# ACF Gallery Custom Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Hello I want to create custom shortcode for ACF gallery. I tried to add the below code in the `functions.php` in my child theme. But I am getting WordPress critical error.

https://gist.github.com/mwangepatrick/01cbf679c3c9e6256c8483c337c274d3

```
<?php

add_shortcode('display_acf_gallery', 'acf_gallery');

function acf_gallery ( $atts ) {

  if ( empty ( $atts['name'] ) ) return "";

    $images = get_field( $atts['name'] );

    if( $images ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

       <div class="thumbnail" style="float:left;" ><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php endif;

}
```

Comment: please post your error message

Comment: sorry i was so dumb. i wrote wrong syntax. the code is correct.

Comment: Then add the fix as answer to close the question.